# local homeomorphism between $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ and $SO(n)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

We have \begin{align*}
\mathfrak{so}(n)&=\{B \in \mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{R});\,\, B+B^{T}=0\}\\
SO(n)&=\{B \in M(n, \mathbb{R}); \,\,\det B=1 \quad \mbox{e} \quad B(B^{T})=I \},
\end{align*} where $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ is the Lie algebra of the Lie group $SO(n).$

My problem is

> Show that $f:\mathfrak{so}(n)\rightarrow SO(n)$ given by$$A \rightarrow (I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$$ define a homeomorphism between an neighborhood of zero in $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ and an neighborhood of $Id_{n}$ in $SO(n)$.

I have no idea where to start this issue. I would like an answer.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Find an inverse of $f$ is a suitable neighbourhood of the identity?

Comment: First of all check that $(I-A)(I-A)^\top =(I+A)(I+A)^\top \implies f(A)f(A)^\top = I$ then look at $F(z) = \frac{1-z}{1+z},z\in \Bbb{C}$ to find the inverse of $f$

Comment: This is called [(generalised) Cayley-transform](http://imar.ro/journals/Revue_Mathematique/pdfs/2018/2/5.pdf). If you search for this, you'll find several proofs.